# Where is my Google App Engine datastore local file, when developing in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a Google App Engine project in Java, using Google Cloud Tools in Eclipse. I added a Maven dependency to my project for using the App Engine Datastore. I run code that both writes to the datastore and reads back from it.

When I browse to the local admin console at **localhost:8080/_ah/admin**, there is no data to view. And from what I've read, there should be a local datastore file in my project's **/WEB-INF/appengine-generated** directory. But that directory never gets created, and obviously neither does the file.

Is there somewhere within my project's properties that define where that file is being created? And is there any reason the admin console is not seeing the data wrote to the datastore?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Tools for Eclipse supports running multiple *Development App Servers*, including having the same App Engine service running in each.  So we can't use the source directory for deployment as the different instances will interfere.

Instead each instance of your service is copied into a deployment area found in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp<X>/<service-name>`. We should do better to expose that location.

When you first interact with the Def App Server's Datastore emulator, you should see some messages to the console identifying the location of the datastore files.

```
Nov 29, 2018 12:25:38 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: High Replication
    Storage: /Users/bsd/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/test-imageservice-3079/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin
Nov 29, 2018 12:25:38 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService load
INFO: The backing store, /Users/bsd/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/test-imageservice-3079/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created.
Nov 29, 2018 12:26:08 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$11 run
INFO: Time to persist datastore: 8 ms
```

You can also tell the Development App Server by editing the server launch configuration and adding `--generated_dir` command-line argument like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply and sorry for my delayed response.

Comment: Thank you @Brian for the reply and sorry for my delayed response. I looked in the directory you specified, and only see a file named datastore-indexes-auto.xml, no local_db.bin. Also, I've read about an admin console you can browse to in your dev app server, which I can, but it shows no data in the datastore even though I know I've written and read back data. So I'm still confused as to why I can't find the files or view any data. Is it possible I'm configured somehow to write to Google's actual servers in the cloud and not my local machine?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose anything without some console logs!  Maybe you could expand on what you mean by the following: _"I added a Maven dependency to my project for using the App Engine Datastore."_  What dependency, and what does your code look like?